# How to restrict user to select only 10 days after the current date in Ionic 4 datepicker

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have added the date-picker for the user but I want the user can select only 10 days after the current date.

This is my **html**:

```
<ion-datetime formControlName="startchallenge" displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" pickerFormat="DD-MMMM-YYYY" placeholder="Select Date" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate"></ion-datetime>
```

This is my **ts**:

```
minDate: String = new Date().toISOString();
maxDate: any = new Date(new Date().setFullDate(new Date().getFullDate() + 2)).toISOString();
```

I want to user can select only 10 days after the current date and min date is today's date.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using moment for this then try this.

first install [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) plugin.

then import it to your component.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

then declare it.

```
export class HomePage {

  public minDate = moment().format();
  public maxDate = moment().add(10, 'd').format();...
```

in html

```
<ion-datetime formControlName="startchallenge" displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" pickerFormat="DD-MMMM-YYYY" placeholder="Select Date" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate"></ion-datetime>
```

this is working in my app.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your **ts** file:

```
minDate: String = new Date().toISOString();
maxDate: any = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 10)).toISOString();
```

This will show the user today's date and User can select 10 days after the current date.